# How is the handling with 'Magic Textures' or similar?

Tags: texturing, materials

For example, if i assign the 'Magic Texture' (or 'Brick Texture) to the standard cube and duplicate this cube three times, i would expect that all these cubes have this texture assigned. But only half of the cubes show this texture, even though it is assigned to all. I am using blender 2.82.7.

[image: Four Cubes]
[image: Eight Cubes]

Am I doing anything wrong? This 'problem' increases when I add more objects to the scene. Why does blender behave like this and how can I make all cubes display the texture?

[Edit]
The file: [image]

Comment: This is quite strange, I could not replicate the issue, can you upload your file?

Comment: I've downloaded your file: i don't have this issue.

Comment: What can i do now? I have checked, that i have installed the latest driver for my graphic card. Are there other things that i could check?